# Copying/Cloning properties of an instance?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, properties, copy, clone

I have a displayobject that has a bunch of properties. What I want to do is to clone this class. I understand it's not possible to do a deep copy of a custom class in AS3 so I have resorted to just copying the properties and then through a clone method create a new instance that has the same exact properties as the original.

I'm having some trouble getting all the properties of the displayobject. Sure I can just call each var one by one and putting it in an array and return that array to the clone like this:

```
function clone():Array
    array.push(displayObject.x);
    array.push(displayObject.y);
    array.push(displayObject.price);
    return array;
```

But that's not really Object Oriented. So I'm looking for way to get all object properties, which then I will put those properties in a new object.

Oh and I'm running on AS3 for Air not Flex, so I can't use the mx.utils.ObjectUtil, which is a way to do this.

Comment: can you use `flash.utils.describeType` ?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't read private properties.

Comment: There is no way to access to private and protected properties

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy private  property. You can use ByteArray to copy properties

Dog is the target class to be clone

```
public class Dog  {

    public function Dog()
    {
    }

    public function setName($name:String):void {
        name = $name;
    }

    public var subDogs:Array = [];

    public var age:int;

    private var name:String;
}
```

And here is how to clone

```
var dog:Dog = new Dog();
dog.subDogs.push(new Dog());
dog.setName("puppy");
dog.age = 15;

registerClassAlias("vo.Dog", vo.Dog);
var dogA:Object = CloneUtil.copy(dog);

var d:Dog = copy(dog) as Dog;

private function copy(source:Object):* {

      var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
      ba.writeObject(source);

      ba.position = 0;

      return ba.readObject();
 }
```

Comment: +1 but you will have to registerClassAlias every custom user type and vector recusivly (probably not a problem here)

Comment: In my case, registerClassAlias  only used in serialize a dictionary contain  cfg files to a game.data file, and deserialize the data file to a dictionary object.  So I think it is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;
    import flash.utils.describeType;
    import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

    public class DynamicClone extends Sprite
    {
        public function DynamicClone()
        {
            var p1 : Player = new Player;
            p1.name = "Simsoft";
            p1.hiddenAccessor = 10;

            var p2 : * = clone( p1 );

            // p2 is a Player instance
            trace(getQualifiedClassName( p2 )); // Player

            // p1 and p2 are not the same instance
            trace(p1 == p2); // False

            // But public properties are cloned
            trace(p2.name); // Simsoft
            trace(p2.hiddenAccessor); // 10
        }

        public function clone( source : Object, cloneGetSet : Boolean = true) : *
        {
            if( !source)
                return null;

            if( source is Array || source is Vector.<*> || source is Vector.<uint> || source is Vector.<int> || source is Vector.<Number> || source is Vector.<Boolean>)
                return source.concat();

            var newInstance : Object = new ( source.constructor );

            // Copy dynamic var
            for(var dynamicVar : String in source)
                newInstance[ dynamicVar ] = source[ dynamicVar ];

            var typeDescription : XML = describeType( source );

            // Copy variables
            for each(var variable : String in typeDescription..variable.@name)
                newInstance[ variable ] = source[ variable ];

            // Copy getter / setter
            if(cloneGetSet)
                for each(var getset : String in typeDescription..accessor.(@access == "readwrite").@name)
                    newInstance[ getset ] = source[ getset ];

            return newInstance;
        }
    }
}

internal class Player {

    // Will be clone
    public var name : String;

    // Won't be clone
    private var _score : uint;

    // Will be clone throught getter/setter
    private var _hidden : uint;

    // Can be clone because we have a getter and a setter
    public function get hiddenAccessor():uint
    {
        return _hidden;
    }

    public function set hiddenAccessor(value:uint):void
    {
        _hidden = value;
    }
}
```